# Accessing all cookies in the Flask test response

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

After I make a request with the Flask test client, I want to access the cookies that the server set. If I iterate over `response.headers`, I see multiple `Set-Cookie` headers, but if I do `response.headers["Set-Cookie"]`, I only get one value. Additionally, the headers are unparsed strings that are hard to test.

```py
response = client.get("/")
print(response.headers['Set-Cookie'])
'mycookie=value; Expires=Thu, 27-Jun-2019 13:42:19 GMT; Max-Age=1800; Path=/'

for item in response.headers:
    print(item)

('Content-Type', 'application/javascript')
('Content-Length', '215')
('Set-Cookie', 'mycookie=value; Expires=Thu, 27-Jun-2019 13:42:19 GMT; Max-Age=1800; Path=/')
('Set-Cookie', 'mycookie2=another; Domain=.client.com; Expires=Sun, 04-Apr-2021 13:42:19 GMT; Max-Age=62208000; Path=/')
('Set-Cookie', 'mycookie3=something; Domain=.client.com; Expires=Thu, 04-Apr-2019 14:12:19 GMT; Max-Age=1800; Path=/')
```

Why does accessing the `Set-Cookie` header only give me one header? How can I access the cookies and their properties for testing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`response.headers` is a [`MultiDict`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict), which provides the [`getlist`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist) method to get all the values for a given key.

```
response.headers.getlist('Set-Cookie')
```

It might be more useful to examine the cookies the client has, rather than the specific raw `Set-Cookie` headers returned by a response. `client.cookie_jar` is a [`CookieJar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html#cookiejar-and-filecookiejar-objects) instance, iterating over it yields [`Cookie`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html#cookie-objects) instances. For example, to get the value of the cookie with the name "user_id":

```
client.post("/login")
cookie = next(
    (cookie for cookie in client.cookie_jar if cookie.name == "user_id"),
    None
)
assert cookie is not None
assert cookie.value == "4"
```

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer guided me to a slightly alternate version depending on what you want to do with the cookie.

I tried using `client.cookie_jar`, but I was testing for a few "non-standard" attributes like `HttpOnly` and `SameSite`. The cookie returned from `client.cookie_jar` does not return them, so I instead inspect the `Set-Cookie` header:

```
from werkzeug.http import parse_cookie

cookies = response.headers.getlist('Set-Cookie')
cookie = next(
    (cookie for cookie in cookies if expected_cookie_name in cookie),
    None
)

assert cookie is not None
cookie_attrs = parse_cookie(cookie)

assert cookie_attrs[expected_cookie_name] == expected_cookie_value
assert 'Secure' in cookie_attrs
assert 'HttpOnly' in cookie_attrs
assert cookie_attrs['SameSite'] == 'Lax'
```